# How to get the total sum for column with joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get sum of the packages from this query, but it doesn't give me the correct result.

```
Select sum(i.cdin_volumewt)
from cdindex i,Performainv p 
where(cdin_deleted Is null  and p.pinv_deleted is null 
     and (p.pinv_InvoiceProperty ='01' or p.pinv_InvoiceProperty is null ) 
     and (p.pinv_Status in('Draft','Posted') or p.pinv_status is null) )
     and i.cdin_startunstufdate between '2016-07-01'  and '2016-07-11'
group by i.cdin_cdindexid
```

This is a screen shot of query result:

[image: ScreenShot of the result]

The expected result is on record with the total cumulative sum of the column records.

Comment: You have to make up your mind by which fields you group. For instance, it does not make sense to group by something that you are also summing up (`i.cdin_NoofPackages`). If you want help, then provide sample data for each of the tables, and the output you expect to get for that sample data.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry because i didn't clarify my question, i tried to group by  i.cdin_cdindexid but also the query result isn't the one i want, i want to get sum of total number of packages. because i want to show it in asp.net page in title=> number of packages is = the total sum

Comment: please post expected result and current result as text

Comment: If you provide sample data for your tables and the expected output, it will be clear what you want. If you want the sum of number of packages, then why are you selecting all those other fields? Just provide sample data and expected outcome and you'll have the answer from someone in a matter of minutes.

Comment: First of all thank you for your replies,  note that i edit the question specifically the query, i want to get the total(Cumulative) sum of the `i.cdin_volumewt` which will be Total Volumetric Weights =722.909 note that i want to print out the result of sum in asp.net label

Comment: sample Data 

Volumetric Weights
20
30
40

i want to get the total sum of 20+30+40 =90 in the result of query

Comment: Show sample data and desired output please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using GROUP BY so you get multiply rows due variety of `i.cdin_cdindexid`. You can get rid of GROUP BY:

```
Select sum(i.cdin_volumewt)
from cdindex i
inner join Performainv p 
     on i.[SOME ID] = p.[SOME ID]
where(cdin_deleted Is null  and p.pinv_deleted is null 
     and (p.pinv_InvoiceProperty ='01' or p.pinv_InvoiceProperty is null ) 
     and (p.pinv_Status in('Draft','Posted') or p.pinv_status is null) )
     and i.cdin_startunstufdate between '2016-07-01'  and '2016-07-11'
```

Or use sub-query:

```
SELECT SUM(p.cdin_volumewt)
FROM (
     Select sum(i.cdin_volumewt) as cdin_volumewt
     from cdindex i
     inner join Performainv p 
          on i.[SOME ID] = p.[SOME ID]
     where(cdin_deleted Is null  and p.pinv_deleted is null 
          and (p.pinv_InvoiceProperty ='01' or p.pinv_InvoiceProperty is null ) 
          and (p.pinv_Status in('Draft','Posted') or p.pinv_status is null) )
          and i.cdin_startunstufdate between '2016-07-01'  and '2016-07-11'
     group by i.cdin_cdindexid
) as p
```

Comment: It doesn't give the correct total which is :722.908851

Comment: You have values like `174168.093947`, how you suppose to get **722**??

Comment: this value is the result of the query that i tried to execute to answer my question.

Comment: I see you have `cdindex i,Performainv p `is that suppose to be some INNER or LEFT JOIN? Because for me it looks like CROSS JOIN. And there is no connection between this 2 tables.

Comment: Add INNER JOIN to my answer, but I don't know on what columns you can join tables.